# ASP.NET Web API Forms Authentication Sub Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I have 2 ASP.NET MVC web applications setup under the same domain. One is just a standard MVC website. The other is a Web API project. For now I am just setup locally.

```
* http://localhost/myapp
* http://localhost/api
```

I am using forms authentication to login in to the web application and then accessing the api application via a jQuery $.get request. Is there a way to share the forms authentication from the web app with the API app? Again these are 2 separate applications but are sharing the same root domain.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I just needed to add a matching machineKey element to the web.config file for both of my applications.

```
<machineKey validationKey="..."
            decryptionKey="..."
            validation="SHA1"
            decryption="AES"
            />
```